# Want to install ubuntu for my lenovo 20332

Tags: system-installation

Like the title says i want to install this on my lenovo but not sure which one to use or how to go about it any help would be appreciated

Comment: Go ahead ;-) There is not a lot we can help with: download the iso, burn it to a dvd or put it on an USB and boot from it. The rest will be point and click mostly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

You want Ubuntu Desktop, as opposed to the server version. Since you are new, I suggest you go for the **LTS** release. Currently the newest is 16.04 (2016,April). **LTS** are long-term-support versions, which ensure you can run them for a few years instead of months without having to upgrade the distribution.

Get the image for **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** on the [official download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), burn it to a DVD or write it to a USB flashdrive. The instructions for doing so can be found on the same download page when you scroll down a bit. If you run into any problems feel free to come back and open another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your USB boot on this site:

[Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)

It depends what you want - and what you want to do. For a lightweight system research Peppermint 6.0 or Lubuntu, other distro's support more eye candy... Some distros for music or video production. I would not install **Ubuntu 16.04LTS** as I don't think all the wrinkles have been sorted out yet; I would go for the **previous LTS** but there are plenty here that would disagree with me.

With the USB option you can try before you install;

**List of available distros on the site**

*Ubuntu,
    Kubuntu,
    Xubuntu,
    Lubuntu,
    Debian,
    openSUSE,
    Arch Linux,
    Damn Small Linux,
    SliTaz,
    Linux Mint,
    Zenwalk,
    Slax,
    Dreamlinux,
    Elive,
    CentOS,
    Mandriva,
    FreeBSD,
    NetBSD,
Fedora,
    PCLinuxOS,
    Sabayon Linux,
    Gentoo,
    MEPIS,
    LinuxConsole,
    Frugalware Linux,
    xPUD,
    Puppy Linux*

Comment: Agree with you on 16.04.