# Installing Ubuntu on a Pentium M i915PM/GM i686 1729 Mhz 1 GB

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to use an old Dell Pentium M i915PM/GM i686 1729 Mhz 1 GB as a dedicated Linux system to run Kali, to learn how to code.

I've burned a couple of ISOs to disc, but still haven't managed to install the OS. When using the installer, it gets so far and then seems to freeze! (I've tested the ISO for errors and downloaded fresh copies of it a few times too, but to no avail)

How can I install the OS, without bricking my old PC? The iso that seemed to get the furthest for me was `lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386`, but it froze too.

Comment: Sorry, but Kali Linux is off-topic here. It is also only recommended for very advanced users with special need for penetration testing tools. As you are a beginner in the Linux world, you should not touch it. So please [edit] your question and remove all that chit-chat, but add a detailed description of your problem when trying to install Ubuntu. Describe every step you made and where you get stuck. Tell us all error messages you encounter. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to code but don't know how to install the os? I would start smaller with your ambitions if you ask me. I agree that lubuntu is best for older pcs. Is there anything in particular you are trying to code for and understanding networks is very vague, anything in particular there as well?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You mentioned Kali, Ubuntu and Lubuntu. Can you at least tell us what exactly are you trying to install? Those are 3 different distros, even though they have a common ground.

Comment: I would like to become a Whitehat, nothing spectacular, no $50,000 rewards or anything, just get started down that road. I'd like to become familiar with Linux and C to start with and prefer being able to get hands on, rather than JUST reading up. I would like the least time-consuming way to write code and compile, which is why I'm trying to get Linux on my old pc and was hoping to make it a dedicated machine for this.

Comment: Comments relevant to my thinking; I admit I'm an idiot noob and am not up-to-date with tech etc. You may think me wanting to be a hacker a bit pie in the sky, however (and I do realise it's massively more complex than what I'm about to say) When I was younger, I taught myself Basic and created various things, have a diploma in IT and created a perpetual calendar in Lotus, amongst other things. I have purposely not bragged about these simple things as they were over 25 years ago and I'm back to square 1, but would like you to know I'm not a TOTAL dreamer.....

Comment: Also, "If you reach for the stars, you may not get there, but you might land on the moon"

Comment: Knowing how to code and knowing which iso will work for me out of the amount of different ones there are, would be two different things in my opinion. Everyone has to start out not knowing anything, we don't download our knowledge! I'm also not a total idiot either! No I'm not up-to-date, but I am capable of learning. Yes I'm asking for help, but who doesn't have even a small bit of support or positive advice when they get started on a new track.........

Comment: I've purposely not tried to pretend I've got lots of experience, because despite having been very competent in basic, msdos and making office programs do things that even my tutors couldn't do over 20 years ago, I know that I know nothing about the things I'm asking about now, and I want to learn. Finding info online isn't easy when there's TBs of the stuff and not all of it is correct, aimed at a beginner or relevant. It's like having to read every page, of every book in a library, just to get a quote from the Gruffalo! I've had useful advice from here, even tho it didn't pan out......

Comment: I also feel like I've had people treating me like a "little" woman sat behind the reception desk (and this is supposed to be the 21st Century)! Personally, I wouldn't dream of talking to anyone like that!

Comment: However, despite all of this, the first step I want to take, is to get Linux and learn C.

Answer (score 1):

If Lubuntu couldn't help you, no other Ubuntu flavor can! All other Buntus are heavier than Lubuntu. For such (old) Pentium you should try some micro-linux (Slax, Puppy, Damn Small Linux, etc) with ultra-lite desktop environment (openbox, icewm, enlightenment, moksha, etc).
But that's not that important. The most important part is the coding, which is usually done in a CLI (command-line) environment. Something similar to Command Prompt from Windows. Sometimes referred as 'bash', 'command line' or 'terminal'. All linuxes have a CLI, a Terminal app of some sort.
Kali is very complex and very dangerous for newbies, it has many 'sharp knives' - tools that can be used in offensive ways. You should start with a main distribution like Debian or Fedora, as you might need strong support forums and communities at first.

Comment: Thank you ipse, I understand that Kali is dangerous, and wanted to have it ready for when I felt competent enough to understand it, after learning to code. I do wish to use it defensively and offensively (on my own private LAN), but only when I understand what I'm doing better. I've tried to figure which iso to get and have looked at Ubuntu and Debian, but because I don't know what to look for specifically, I've been trying ones I think are the best fit (ie 32b) and it's like looking for a needle in a haystack with all of the various CD isos available.

Comment: Try Elive (debian-based) or Bodhi (Ubuntu-based). Very small, yet very beautiful to the eye.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775510/want-to-install-ubuntu-for-my-lenovo-20332/775990#775990) as there are some similarities in the question you are asking.

I agree with the advice given above about Kali - stick to a small Linux distro to learn about coding. **And as you can see plenty of support with the 'Buntus** --- which you will need if you are a noob.

Good luck