# Installing Ubuntu to USB stick 'File is broken'

Tags: windows-7

I've been trying to install Ubuntu to my usb but every time i try, while its extracting the files on every file it says 'File is broken' next to it.

I downloaded the Ubuntu file. Its named `ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso`

Heres what happens after the extracting thing finishes at 99% and it just sits there i have to close it, but then the original program starts doing this:

```
Extract: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\syslinux.exe... 100%
Extract: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\syslinux603.exe... 100%
Extract: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\syslinux.cfg... 100%
Extract: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\7zG.exe... 100%
Extract: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\7z.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\chain.c32... 100%
Extract: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\menu.c32... 100%
Extract: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\vesamenu.c32... 100%
Extract: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\mbrid
Create folder: F:\uui
Copy to F:\uui\syslinux.cfg
Executing syslinux on F:
Execute: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\syslinux.exe -maf -d /uui F:
Syslinux Errors 0
Creating Label UUI on F:
Extracting the iso: The progress bar will not move until finished. Please be patient...
Execute: "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\7zG.exe" x "C:\Users\user\Downloads\ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso" -o"F:\" -y -x![BOOT]*
Editing Configuration Files
Extract: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\Uni-USB-Installer-Copying.txt... 100%
Extract: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\Uni-USB-Installer-Readme.txt... 100%
Extract: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\license.txt... 100%
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\Uni-USB-Installer-Copying.txt -> F:\Uni-USB-Installer-Copying.txt
1 File(s) copied
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\Uni-USB-Installer-Readme.txt -> F:\Uni-USB-Installer-Readme.txt
1 File(s) copied
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw27AC.tmp\license.txt -> F:\license.txt
1 File(s) copied
Checking if we need to replace vesamenu.c32, menu.c32, and chain.c32
Found chain.c32 at F:\isolinux\chain.c32
Copy to F:\isolinux\chain.c32
Found vesamenu.c32 at F:\isolinux\vesamenu.c32
Copy to F:\isolinux\vesamenu.c32
Installation Done, Process is Complete!
```

and after that, i restart the computer and it just boots to normal windows (Im using windows 7, with the latest ubuntu) That was the *'Pen drive linux'* program i was using. I then tried the software that the ubuntu website said to use, Rufus, and i tried that and as it was doing its thing it says

`"Error: ISO extraction failure."`

So, i dont know what im doing wrong and hopefully someone will know whats wrong. I am a first timer with linux..

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Did you follow the [official instructions to create a bootable Ubuntu USB drive in Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)? At which point does the error in your question occur? Did you [verify the integrity](//help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the disk image(s) used as source to create the installation medium?

Comment: Yes , i followed the instructions there, and the error occurred when i click start on the Rufus usb installer, it would load for a few seconds then a erro tab would open. And i dont know what verifying the integrity is?

Comment: Could you please verify the integrity of the installation medium according to the instructions linked in my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Unetbootin route; see this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775510/want-to-install-ubuntu-for-my-lenovo-20332/775990#775990) to create the USB image on the **website** rather than on your machine.